# When will SharePoint SE be available in the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, data-explorer

I'm wondering when this site will be available for query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

The [best I can find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56300/when-will-stackexchange-sites-be-available-in-data-explorer) is that it usually takes 4-6 months from the start of a new site, but as we've been around in a previous incarnation for much longer, will we still need to wait that long?

I'd like to use it to find out which tags we're weak in answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta sites are not part of the Data Explorer.  They are added in the first dump after the site's graduation.

Comment: When should we expect SharePoint to be available from Data Explorer? The dump is done, but the site isnt available yet from Data Explorer

Comment: Found this after chatting on Teachers Lounge http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109/when-will-the-data-dump-for-er-and-other-beta-sites-be-made-available/110#110